# Stokes equation: when to use gradient or its symmetric part?

Tags: fluid-statics

Sometimes appears

$$\boxed{\:\:\:-div(\nu\nabla u)+\nabla p=f \:\:\:\vphantom{\frac12}} \tag{01}$$

and in other places

$$\boxed{\:\:\:-div(\nu\,eps(u))+\nabla p=f\:\:\:\vphantom{\frac12}}\tag{02}$$

where

$$eps(u)=\dfrac{1}{2}(\nabla u+\nabla u^t)\tag{03}$$

**From physic point of view, what difference this two expressions have?**

Obviously, when $\nabla u=\nabla u^t$, then $eps(u)=\nabla u$, but, what represents $\nabla u=\nabla u^t$ (from physic point of view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that,for an incompressible fluid, 
$$
\nabla \cdot (\nabla \mathbf{u})^T = \nabla  (\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u}) = 0
$$
I expect your value of a half is erroneous.